# Activity и загрузка памяти

Tags: android

Пишу андроид приложение на дипломный проект. У меня очень много Activity, кто-то говорил, что окна нужно делать не через Activity, т.к загружает память. Тогда как делать окна?

Comment: Может, имелись в виду фрагменты?

Answer (score 4):

Стандартный паттерн сейчас такой:

1. Есть 1 `Activity` - без `Activity` нет приложения с фронтендом
2. К `Activity` навешивается нужное количество `Fragment`

и да, не забудьте убить того, кто говорит, что `Activity` потребляют много памяти, здесь даже дело не в этом, а в том, что каждый конкретный момент времени в памяти требуется ровно 1 `Activty`, остальные система может выгрузить из памяти в любой момент, так что это не является проблемой.

Answer (score 3):

Да нормально все, можно через кучу Activity делать. Система сама выгрузит неактивные, а потом создаст в случае необходимости. Надо только быть готовыми сохранять и восстанавливать данные в них. Что нужно делать и в случае 1 активити и кучи фрагментов, т. к. система и 1 активити может грохнуть, например, при повороте экрана или если ваше приложение будет в фоне.